# Why the current directory changes

Tags: c, windows, winapi, directory

After a call of `GetOpenFileName` the current directory of the process changes to the directory of the file opened file by the `GetOpenFileName`.

---

How can I keep the default current directory instead ?

Comment: By saving it, and then restoring it, once the call returns. While that answers your question, what you **really** should be doing instead is NOT relying on the current working directory altogether. You just experienced one reason, why.

Comment: I need to create files in the local directory fast, because another program from the same directory can only open local files and that's the way both the programs communicate with each other. Thanks by the way.

Comment: So then, go ahead and create all the files you need. Why do you insist, that this requires relying on the current working directory, though?

Comment: Portability issues.. it is really not the best but the only thing I can do at least without spending much efforts .

Comment: Saving 15 minutes today will cost you days, or weeks, maybe months down the road, when it comes to supporting a bug you implemented on purpose. And what sort of *"portability"* relies on an invariant, that isn't?

Comment: This is documented behaviour that cannot be suppressed. You can save the current directory, and restore after `GetOpenFileName` returns. Or you can use `IFileDialog` and tell it not to modify the current directory.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What is IFileDialog ?

Comment: It is something that every search engine can locate for you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Right, then let's stop using StackOverflow 'cuz it's useless

Comment: Stack Overflow does not exist as a means to get people to type into search engines for you. We like to help people learn how to be self-sufficient. If you don't want to learn how to use a search engine then you should look elsewhere for help. This is not the site for you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've seen an arcane amount of 'good' answers in Stack overflow but nothing one cannot find himself using the search engine.

Comment: Not so. Plenty of things are easy to find by searching. Plenty of things are really hard to search for. In this case, IFileDialog is obviously in the former category. Incidentally, as is this question because the behaviour you observe is well documented.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I cannot have a clue whether you are willing to document it here or you want me to search myself. So can say "Search for ..." so that I can assume it is easy to be found. I respect S/O but there is no such measuring "hard or easy to be found somewhere else". There isn't even "Spoon Feeding" term. So yes. I really cannot know.

Comment: Documentation: [Common Item Dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913.aspx). Specifically, [IFileOpenDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775834.aspx).

Comment: @Malina I think the first sentence of the first comment exactly answers your question. Use [`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`SetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Yeah I already figured it out. Used _getcwd though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How can I keep the default current directory instead ?

If you read the [`OPENFILENAME` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx), there is an `OFN_NOCHANGEDIR` flag for that exact purpose:

> Restores the current directory to its original value if the user changed the directory while searching for files.

Despite what the documentation claims, this flag is supported in `GetOpenFileName()`.

Also see Raymond Chen's blog article on this subject:

[Why does the common file dialog change the current directory?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101112-00/?p=12293)

Comment: Huh.  The documentation says that flag causes the current directory to be restored to its original value, but Raymond's article says that it stops the current directory from being changed; do you happen to know what actually happens in practice?  (It doesn't matter for single-threaded programs, of course.)

Comment: I read articles, I don't copy paste sample codes. I ignored it, because it said that it won't have any effect. I should've remember winapi doc is a sheer example of badly-written doc.

Comment: `OFN_NOCHANGEDIR` restores the original working directory when the dialog is closed. The dialog can still change the working directory while the user is navigating around the file system from inside the dialog.

Comment: OK, thanks.  That means this solution will only work properly in the case where only the GUI thread uses the current directory, and I guess you could also fool yourself if you open a file while processing, e.g., a timer message.  (That's probably OK for the OP, I just mention it for the benefit of future readers.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: The working directory is global to the process, and can affect multiple threads. There is a comment about that in Raymond's blog article: "*When you specify OFN_NOCHANGEDIR, GetOpenFileName still changes the current directory while it is running. The only difference is that this flag restores the previous current directory when the function exits. This means that in a multi-thread application, you must be careful not to use relative paths in your other threads while GetOpenFileName is running.*"

Comment: According to [this comment](http://bytepointer.com/resources/old_new_thing/20101112_315_why_does_the_common_file_dialog_change_the_current_directory.htm#comment-873863) in Raymond Chen's article, the `OFN_NOCHANGEDIR` flag is supported for `GetOpenFileName` as of Win Vista.

Answer (score 4):

The current directory exists because it is very convenient for command line tools.  It generally isn't very much use for GUI applications, which is probably why Microsoft's developers didn't worry about allowing GetOpenFileName() to change it.  There is of course the occasional edge case, and you might be dealing with one of them, although it is hard to tell from your question as written.  (Are you absolutely sure that you want the current directory and not, for example, the directory containing your executable?)

At any rate, if you *do* want the current directory, the safest approach is to retrieve it as soon as the program starts, and use that saved value to construct fully qualified paths.  Don't just restore the original current directory whenever you think it might have been changed, build the fully qualified paths yourself.  This is especially important in multi-threaded code, or in code that might need to be multi-threaded in the future (i.e., pretty much everything) but it also eliminates the risk of overlooking one or more code paths where the current directory might change.